# List inheritance: "extend" vs "+" vs "+="

Tags: python, list, inheritance

I would like to understand why the following three, extremely simple, python codes give (apparently) inconsistent answers. It's just a toy exercise to understand what's happening, not a real-world problem. The class myList(list) inherits from list and defines a method "add" that should mimic the well-known "extend" method. I've tried to do this in three ways, with the direct use of extend, with the + operator and with +=. However, with great surprise, I get inconsistent answers. Notice that, among the three codes, a single line (inside the add method) changes.

**CODE 1: self.extend(item)**

```
class myList(list): 

    def add(self,item):
        self.extend(item)

l = myList([1,2])
l.add([3,4])
print(l)
```

Prints `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

**CODE 2: self = self + item**

```
class myList(list):

    def add(self,item):
        self = self + item

l = myList([1,2])
l.add([3,4])
print(l)
```

Prints `[1, 2]`

**CODE 3: self += item**

```
class myList(list):

    def add(self,item):
        self += item

l = myList([1,2])
l.add([3,4])
print(l)
```

Prints `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

I am a bit confused... what's happening?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

```
    self = self + item
```

does not modify the object, only the local variable inside the method.

By using `+` the interpreter is calling `__add__` in `list`, which creates a new list, and you're then making the `self` variable point to it within the `add` method, and when the method exits its value is discarded.

On the other hand, the `+=` version calls the `__iadd__` method of the `list` class, which updates its contents as expected.